# Kentico DocumentHelper.GetDocuments with multiple types not returning latest version

Tags: kentico

I have a query that uses multiple types like so:

```
DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
.Type("Class1", q => q.Columns("Col1, Col2"))
.Type("Class2", q => q.Columns("Col1, Col2").Where("Col1", QueryOperator.Equals, true))
.Path(path, PathTypeEnum.Children)
.NestingLevel(1)
.Published(false)
.OrderByAscending("Col1")
.WithCoupledColumns();
```

I've tried with and without `.Published` and `.LatestVersion` (DocumentHelper shouldn't need them anyway) but to no avail, the query only returns the latest published version when I use multiple types.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.OnCurrentSite()` see if it changes the outcome.